# Exo player al cambiar de orientacion video comienza desde el principio.

Tags: java, android

Llevo dias intentando solucionar el problema y nada..
Estoy intentado implementar el ExoPlayer en una applicacion en la que salen videos y instruccione y recetas de cocina.
El video funciona normal y todo bien pero cuando cambio la orientacion el video empieza desde el principio no de la posicion anterior. He intentado de todo pero no consigo solucionarlo.
Voy a dar mi source code, el Exo player esta en el StepFragment Class.
https://github.com/AhmedHamdan54/iBake

Comment: Listo, actualice el código de la respuesta, haciendo lo que quieres.

Comment: Perfecto muchisimas gracias por todo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes un error grave en el código que hace que en algunos dispositivos explote:

> com.example.ahmed.ibake E/rsC++: RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
>       RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
>       RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Blur radius out of 0-25 pixel bound

En tu archivo `styles.xml`, tienes varias propiedades de `shadowRadius`, debes establecer un `shadowRadius` **menor o igual a 25px** en una vista, porque de lo contrario te provocara este error de segmentación. Esto se debe a [RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute), más específicamente [ScriptIntrinsicBlur](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html#setRadius(float)).

---

**Con relación al problema de reproducción:**

Estas sobreescribiendo tanto el metodo `onStart` como el `onResume`, con varias validaciones. Esto hace que prepare varios `ExoPlayer` al mismo tiempo en algunos dispositivos. Tanto el `onStart`, `onStop` y `onDetach` deben ser eliminados. Basta con sobreescribir `onPause` y `onResume` para detener y resumir la reproduccion y el `onDestroy` para limpiar los objetos de reproducción.

El problema al girar la pantalla sucede en los parametros que envias en el `ExoPlayer` al momento de prepararlo, recuerda que al girar la pantalla el configuration cambia del dispositivo, haciendo que se recree la actividad y obviamente los hijos de esta.

Segun la [documentacion oficial](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.html#prepare-com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource-) con relacion al metodo `prepare` del `ExoPlayer`:

> *mediaSource* - The MediaSource to play.
>
> *resetPosition* - Whether the playback position should be reset to the
>   default position in the first Timeline.Window. If false, playback will
>   start from the position defined by Player.getCurrentWindowIndex() and
>   Player.getCurrentPosition().
>
> *resetState* - Whether the timeline, manifest, tracks and track
>   selections should be reset. Should be true unless the player is being
>   prepared to play the same media as it was playing previously (e.g. if
>   playback failed and is being retried).

En tu método de preparación `initializePlayer()` de `StepFragment` tienes lo siguiente:

```
simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
```

Si te fijas, el segundo parámetro, que es *resetPosition* lo estas enviando en `true` cuando debería de ser `false`, ya que la documentación dice que si lo envías `true`, este inicializara desde la posición por defecto y no en la posición definida en `seekTo`.

Dicho esto tu **StepFragment.java** debería quedar así:

```
package com.example.ahmed.ibake;


import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.example.ahmed.ibake.Recipes.Steps;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.example.ahmed.ibake.databinding.FragmentStepBinding;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;


import icepick.Icepick;
import icepick.State;

public class StepFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String KEY_STEP_OBJECT = "stepObject";


    @State
    Steps step;

    @State
    long currentPosition = 0;
    private static final String KEY_WINDOW = "window";
    private static final String PLAYER_POSITION = "position";
    private FragmentStepBinding binding;
    private SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = null;
    private static final String KEY_AUTO_PLAY = "auto_play";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()),
                R.layout.fragment_step, container, false);

        if (null != step.getVideoUrl() && !(TextUtils.isEmpty(step.getVideoUrl()))) {
            initializePlayer();
        } else {
            binding.expPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (null != binding.tvShortDescriptionStep) {
            binding.tvShortDescriptionStep.setText(step.getShortDescription());
            binding.tvFullDescription.setText(step.getDescription());
        } else {

            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
            getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (simpleExoPlayer == null) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(simpleExoPlayer != null) {
            currentPosition = simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            simpleExoPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (simpleExoPlayer != null) {
            simpleExoPlayer.stop();
            simpleExoPlayer.release();
            simpleExoPlayer = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        if (null != simpleExoPlayer) {
            simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            currentPosition = simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            outState.putLong(PLAYER_POSITION, currentPosition);
            outState.putBoolean("state", simpleExoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady());
        }

        Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    public void setStep(Steps step) {
        this.step = step;
    }

    public void updateStep(Steps step) {

        if (null != binding.tvShortDescriptionStep) {
            binding.tvShortDescriptionStep.setText(step.getShortDescription());
            binding.tvFullDescription.setText(step.getDescription());
        }

        if (null == simpleExoPlayer) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);


        if (null != step.getVideoUrl() && !(TextUtils.isEmpty(step.getVideoUrl()))) {

            binding.expPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(step.getVideoUrl());
            MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
            simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
            simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        } else {
            binding.expPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
        return new ExtractorMediaSource(uri,
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua"),
                new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
    }

    private void initializePlayer() {

        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                new DefaultRenderersFactory(getContext()),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(),
                new DefaultLoadControl());

        binding.expPlayer.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
        simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(step.getVideoUrl());
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);
    }
```

}

y en tu **AndroidManifest.xml** debebes especificar el `configChanges` para prevenir el recreado de la Actividad que maneja el reproductor, en este caso `StepActivity`:

```
<activity android:name=".StepActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"/>
```

Para hacer cambios visuales de manera manual al cambiar la configuración, por ejemplo, establecer el video en `FullScreenMode`, agregar el metodo sobreescrito en `StepFragment`:

```
    @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            // Si es landscape, cambia los valores visuales
            if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
             // Ocultar la barra de estado
                getActivity().getWindow()
                .getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            // Ocultar la barra de accion
            if(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null)
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

                binding.expPlayer.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }
            else {
                // Mostrar la barra de estado
                getActivity().getWindow()
                .getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);

                // Mostrar la barra de accion
                if(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null)
                    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();

                binding.expPlayer.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())));

            }
        }
```

Al ponerlo en modo `FullScreen` debes hacer un resize del Layout por eso debes Agrega al root del Layout la siguiente propiedad:

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, tu código axml debería quedar así:

**fragment_step.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/exp_player"
            app:resize_mode="fixed_height"
            app:auto_show="false"
            />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/exp_player"
            >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_short_description_step"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="@color/ingre_qty_text"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                tools:text="This will show the short description of the text."
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_full_description"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/ingre_qty_text"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                tools:text="This will show the full description of the text."
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: @Ahmed ya pude solucionarlo. Es como te dije, lo unico que ellos agregan todos los casos en el manifest. En tu Manifest en el Activity de .StepActivity debes agregar: `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"` y en tu Fragment, sobreescribe `onCreate` y escribe `setRetainInstance(true);` en seguida te modifico el codigo en mi respuesta agregando el onCreate.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Si que sige lo cargado, pero ahora no se vuelve full screen al cambiar de orientacion, habria una soluction para eso?

Comment: @Ahmed ahora hay que ver como hacer eso, ya que debe ser una solución manual, porque `configChanges` evita recrear las vistas. Yo vere si puedo solucionar eso también, pero ya eso seria otro tema, si la solución te funciono puedes aceptar la respuesta y yo te notifico cuando lo actualice en caso de que logre hacerlo.

Comment: Ah claro perdon :) Muchas gracias por todo de verdad.

Comment: @Ahmed ya actualice el codigo, tienes que sobreescribir el metodo que cambia la configuracion para determinar si estas en `Landscape` o en `Portrait` y hacer el resize manual de la vista. Se llama `onConfigurationChanged` revisa si te funciona y dejame saber. Me guie de los layouts, en portrait tiene `200dp`, asi que asigne `200dp` de manera manual en los `LayoutParams` convirtiendo la unidad a dp con `TypedValue` y en Landscape ambos `match_parent`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, habria alguna forma de quitar la barra? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbSoU.png

Comment: @Ahmed ya edite la respuesta nuevamente, agregando lo que quieres, sobre ponerlo de pantalla completa, estilo Youtube. Saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por todo, ok lo hare ahora mismo gracias Andres